# jQuery unbinding inside of a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some JavaScript that needs to run before a form is submitted. Part of the JavaScript that runs is a chunked file uploader which runs asynchronously: ([resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/)).

The library provides a function to listen for when uploading is complete. When I unbind the submit event inside of this function, the form does not submit and the page just reloads. However, the form will submit when the unbind is not inside the function (albeit before the file uploader has done its work).

This code does not submit the form (`r` is an object instance of of the chunked file uploader):

```
$('#Form1').submit(function (e) {
    var form = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    r.upload(); //async

    r.on('complete', function () {
        form.unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

This code will submit the form (but obviously too early, before the uploader can do its work):

```
$('#Form1').submit(function (e) {
    var form = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    r.upload(); //async

    form.unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

For clarification, the chain of events I want to happen is this:

1. User hits submit.
2. JavaScript uploader uploads a file to a webservice.
3. Once upload is complete, web form gets posted.

EDIT: The crux of the problem is this:

```
r.on('complete', function () {
    form.unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

The above code snippet does not behave in the same way as this:

`form.unbind('submit').submit();`

And I cannot figure out why.

Comment: And you want a traditional form post with a full page reload, right?

Comment: It should be fine - what you're doing looks okay.  Are you sure that the `complete` handler is being fired?  Just put a `console.log` in there so you can see it's happened.

Comment: Here's a working example... https://jsfiddle.net/smqkeveo/

Comment: Yes, it's an ASP.NET form. (I'm not particularly familiar with these). The complete handler definitely fires, and the page refreshes itself but the form does not get submitted and the page redirected.

Comment: That JSfiddle does not reflect what I'm tying to do. The `r.upload()` function can take a long time to complete.

Comment: `form[0].submit()` would be better (no need to unbind and no chance of it being prevented because it triggers no events) but i see no reason for what you have to not work.

Answer (score -1):

<del>I do not see why you need to unbind event, but if you need to fire only once you can use .one to attache event. It automatically unbinds after it fires.</del>

I think I misread your question. The code below works for me. I think is pretty clear: define function to kill submit and start upload; on resumable complete unbinds function then trigger form submit.

```
function pseudoSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return r.upload();
};
r.on('complete', function () {
   $('#Form1').off('submit', pseudoSubmit ).submit();
});

$('#Form1').on('submit', pseudoSubmit );
```